# Unable to push a repository on github

Tags: git, github

I try to push my local git repository to github with no success.

The steps I followed so far are:

- Create the repository in git with `git init .`
- Add a file to the staging area using `git add .`
- Make a commit using `git commit -m "some text"`
- Create new repository on github
- Establish connection with github via `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myreponame`
- Make a push with `git push -u origin main`

At this point is where I should be able to see my files in the browser. But when I refresh my repository page on github, nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you pushed to github with `git push`? git does not sync with a remote repository until you explicit tell it with `git pull` to pull changes from the remote repository or `git push` to push changes to the remote repository

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're doing a `git push` which is the command that acutally uploads stuff to github

Comment: **I try the command [** `git push -u origin main` **] and I get [** `error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/GenaroHacker/my-new-repo.git` **] I don't know what it means**

Comment: Your branch is called `master`, so the correct command would be `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `git push origin master` to push the changes in your github remote repo Cause You're on `master` branch in your local